# What does "No apt package "yt-dlp", but there is a snap with that name" mean?

Tags: apt, package-management

I just wanted to install yt-dlp with: `sudo apt install yt-dlp`. But I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "yt-dlp", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install yt-dlp"

E: Unable to locate package yt-dlp
```

**Question** What does `snap` mean?

Answer (score 5):

Snap is just a software packaging and deployment system made by Canonical (Ubuntu) It is made to make it easy to install and update software on linux system

For your problem it just mean that there is no "yt-dlp" package available in the Ubuntu repositories but it also said that there is a snap package with the same name available using snap "snap install yt-dlp"

Notice that you can simply install yt-dlp with the package installer for python instead of snap with this command:

```
pip install yt-dlp
```

Comment: Note that you need `apt install python3-pip` for this, which may not come with every Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310688/sudo-pip-install-vs-pip-install-user for concerns about using `sudo` with `pip install`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni you right, fixed it

Comment: @FedKad fixed it, and this package doesnt need sudo aniways